# awk using an index key over a range

Tags: arrays, awk

I have an awk script that I normally run in parallel using an outside variable $a.

```
 awk -v a=$a '$4>a-5 && $4<a+5 {print $10,$4}' INFILE
```

It would of course run much faster using an array so I tried something like this to get it to do the same thing ($2 in LISTFILE being the search value for $4 in INFILE

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=($2-5);next}$4 in a{if ($4>a[$4] && $4<a[$4]+10 {print} LISTFILE INFILE
```

This of course did not work because awk scanned until it reached the key and then started the testing the if statement, so only the downstream range was found.  Unfortunately this isn't a continuous list, so often there is no $2-5 value, otherwise I would use that as the key for the array.

obviously I know how to do this using a combo of awk and bash, but I was wondering if there was an awk only solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer addresses the actual question asked and fixes the `awk` script. But perhaps I have missed the point. If you want speed, and don't mind making more use of your multi-core processor, you can use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). Here's an implementation that will launch 4 jobs at a time:

```
awk_cmd='$4 > var - 5 && $4 < var + 5 { print $10, $4 }'

parallel -j 4 "awk -v var={} '$awk_cmd' INFILE" :::: LISTFILE
```

As you can see, this will read `INFILE` up to four times concurrently. This answer, after adjustment of the number of jobs, should provide very similar performance to your parallel implementation that you describe using your shell. Therefore, you may like to split up your `LISTFILE` into smaller chunks and set `awk_cmd` to the command posted in my previous answer. There may be an optimal way to process you input, but that would largely depend on the size of `INFILE` and the number of elements in `LISTFILE`. HTH.

---

---

**TESTING:**

Create `LISTFILE`:

```
paste - - < <(seq 16) > LISTFILE
```

Create `INFILE`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1; i<=9999999; i++) { print i, i, i, int(i * rand()), i, i, i, i, i, i } }' > INFILE
```

**RESULTS:**

*TEST1:*

```
time awk 'FNR==NR { a[$2]; next } { for (i in a) { if ($4 > i - 5 && $4 < i + 5) { print $10, $4 } } }' LISTFILE INFILE >/dev/null

real    0m45.198s
user    0m45.090s
sys     0m0.160s
```

*TEST2:*

```
time for i in $(seq 1 2 16); do awk -v var="$i" '$4 > var - 5 && $4 < var + 5 { print $10, $4 }' INFILE; done >/dev/null

real    0m55.335s
user    0m54.433s
sys     0m0.953s
```

*TEST3:*

```
awk_cmd='$4 > var - 5 && $4 < var + 5 { print $10, $4 }'

time parallel --colsep "\t" -j 4 "awk -v var={2} '$awk_cmd' INFILE" :::: LISTFILE >/dev/null

real    0m28.190s
user    1m42.750s
sys     0m1.757s
```

---

---

**My reply to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24295365/751863) answer:**

**1:**

`The awk1 script does not run much faster than the awk script.`

A 15% time saving is pretty significant in my opinion.

`I suspect because it scans the LISTFILE for every line in the INFILE.`

Yes, essentially. The `awk1` script loops through `INFILE` just once.

`So number of lines scanned using the array with for (i in a) = NR(INFILE)*NR(LISTFILE).`

Close. But don't forget that by using an array, we actually remove any duplicate values in `LISTFILE`.

`This is the same number of lines you would scan by going through the INFILE repeatedly with the bash script.`

This statement is therefore only true when `LISTFILE` contains no duplicates. Even if `LISTFILE` never contains any dups, having to read a single file multiple times is best avoided.

**2:**

`Running awk and awk2 in a different folder produced different results (where my 4 min result came from versus the ~2 min result here, not sure what the difference is because they are next door in the parent directory.`

What four minute result? When benchmarking this sort of thing, you should stop writing the output to disk. If your machine has some background process going on when your running your tests, you will only end up biasing your results with the write speed of your disk. Use `/dev/null` instead.

**3:**

`Awk and Awk2 are essentially the same. Any idea why awk2 runs faster?`

If you remove the pipe to `sort` and `uniq` you will get a better idea of where the time difference is. You will find that doing `$4 > i - 5 && $4 < i + 5` is grossly different to doing `$4 < i + 5 && $4 > i - 5`. If `awkout.txt` is the same as `awkout.txt`, you are spending time processing duplicates.

**4:**

The second command you posted here avoids this test: `$4 > i - 5 && $4 < i + 5`. I wouldn't think that that alone would warrant a 90% improvement in runtime. Something smells wrong. Would you mind re-running your tests writing to `/dev/null` and posting the contents of `LISTFILE` and `INFILE`? If those two files are confidential, could you provide some example files with the amount of content equal to the originals?

**Other thoughts:**

To me, it looks like something along these lines would also work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { for (i=$2-4;i<$2+5;i++) a[i]; next } $4 in a { b[$10,$4] } END { print length b }' LISTFILE INFILE
```

Comment: I've posted my results and reply below in an answer.

Comment: @jeffpkamp: I have added a reply to your questions above. HTH.

Comment: ah, that last function is what I was looking for from the beginning! I tweaked the end of it to have "{b[$10,$4]++}END{for (i in b) print i,b[i]}'"  This subs for my sort | uniq -c function step and still only take 12 seconds.  I think the 90% gain in run time is due to only reading each file once (reads 8+20million lines), rather than looping on either one( reads 8*20million lines), so it runs ~8x faster.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jeffpkamp: Awesome. Glad we got there in the end :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to add the keys of `LISTFILE` to an array, then, as you process `INFILE` (line by line), test each key in your array with your 'if' statement. You can do this using the following construct or similar:

```
for (i in a) { print i, a[i] }
```

Here's some untested code that may help get you started. Notice how I have not assigned any values to my keys:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$2]; next } { for (i in a) { if ($4 > i - 5 && $4 < i + 5) { print $10, $4 } } }' LISTFILE INFILE
```

Comment: This seems to work though it slows down the awk script considerably from 22s to 7m 30s.  I guess doing it in parallel with a bash script might be the way to do it, unless you can think of a way to speed this script up.

Comment: I don't believe that that time comparison is a fair one. It looks like you're comparing your first script, which searches for a SINGLE variable, to a script that takes MULTIPLE variables. A better comparison would involve running your first script over and over again for each variable in `LISTFILE` then summing the walltimes. I can guarantee you that the code posted in this answer will be faster because you will read `INFILE` just once. If you want speed, process `INFILE` in parallel. I have added another answer below.

Comment: Oddly, it is still slower for the direct comparison, for 8 variables the bash loop took 2:10 while the awk script took 4:23.  Obviously the awk script must be looping back through the INFILE multiple times.  If I make an expanded list of $2 from the LISTFILE to contain -5 to +5, it only takes 12 seconds, which is what I was hoping for.  I suppose I could just make an awk script to expand LISTFILE, then run it as an array for much quicker results.

Comment: No. The AWK script above loops through `INFILE` just once. Time is spent looping through and testing the array values. With eight variables, using an array to hold and test the values in `LISTFILE` is faster than having to read and process `INFILE` eight times consecutively. Please see my test results posted below. Would you happen to have some example data that I would be able to benchmark?

Answer (score 0):

Steves answer above is the correct answer to the question.  Below is a comparison of array and non array ways to handle the problem.

I created a test program to look at two different scenarios and the results from each.  The test programs code is here:

```
echo time for bash

time for line in `awk '{print $2}' $1` ; do awk -v a=$line '$4>a-5&&$4<a+5{print $4,$10}' $2 ; done | sort | uniq -c > bashout.txt

echo time for awk
time awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]; next}{for (i in a) {if ($4>i-5&&$4<i+5) print $10,$4}}' $1 $2 |sort | uniq -c > awkout.txt

echo time for awk2

time awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]; next}{for (i in a) {if ($4<i+5&&$4>i-5) print $10,$4}}' $1 $2 |sort | uniq -c > awk2out.txt

echo time for awk3
time awk '{a=$2;b=$1;for (i=a-4;i<a+5;i++) print b,i}' $1 > LIST2;time awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2];next}$4 in a{print $10,$4}' LIST2 $2 | sort | uniq -c > awk3out.txt
```

Here is the output:

```
time for bash
real    2m22.394s
user    2m15.938s
sys     0m6.409s

time for awk
real    2m1.719s
user    2m0.919s
sys     0m0.782s

time for awk2
real    1m49.146s
user    1m47.607s
sys     0m1.524s

time for awk3
real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s

real    0m12.788s
user    0m12.096s
sys     0m0.695s
```

4 observations/questions

1. The awk1 script does not run much faster than the awk script.  I suspect because it scans the LISTFILE for every line in the INFILE.  So number of lines scanned using the array with for (i in a) = NR(INFILE)*NR(LISTFILE).  This is the same number of lines you would scan by going through the INFILE repeatedly with the bash script.
2. Running awk and awk2 in a different folder produced different results (where my 4 min result came from versus the ~2 min result here, not sure what the difference is because they are next door in the parent directory.
3. Awk  and Awk2 are essentially the same.  Any idea why awk2 runs faster?
4. Making an expanded LIST2 from the LISTFILE and using that as the array makes the program run significantly faster, at the cost of increasing the memory footprint. Considering how small the list I"m looking at is (only 200-300 long) that seems to be the way to go, even over doing this in parallel.